# Recursive function not breaking

Tags: arrays, swift, recursion

I want to iterate over a 2D array and make subarrays whenever I find a different value in a specific column. Example:

```
TEST <----- This value should be ignored. Start counting at index 1.
A
A
A
-------- split here --------
B
B
B
-------- split here --------
C
-------- split here --------
```

This results in 3 arrays.

1. array1: [A,A,A]
2. array2: [B,B,B]
3. array3: [C]

My solution to this problem was a recursive method which takes the 2D array:

```
static func splitArray(fromArray array: [[String]], startIndex: Int = 1) {
    for x in startIndex..<array.count {
        if array.indices.contains(x+1)  {
            if (array[x][7]) != array[x+1][7] {
                splitArray(fromArray: array, startIndex: x+1)
            }
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

In this method I do the following:

1. Go through the array starting at index 1.
2. Compare the current index with the next index. If the next index has a different value split the array if not resume iterating.
3. To prevent array out of bounds I check if there's a next index - if there is no next index break the method (which should be called once the whole array has been iterated over)

Extra info:

1. The magic number 7 is the column in my 2D array I want to iterate over.
2. The method does reach the break command .. but somehow it jumps back in the method although it doesn't get called by the recursive splitArray call.
3. This method doesn't create the subarrays yet since the logic at this point is broken.

Why doesn't my function break? It does do its work - it splits correctly but then it starts over when it shouldn't.

P.S: If there's any coding advice I'd highly appreciate it, I feel this code in general is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
static func split(_ array: [[String]], startIndex: Int = 1) {
    for x in startIndex..<array.count {
        if array.indices.contains(x+1)  {
            if (array[x][7]) != array[x+1][7] {
                split(array, startIndex: x+1)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The "fix" was to include the break after calling the recursive function. I guess the for loop resumed after calling split.